Oracle ADF rest batch processing, can I reference the payload from operation 1 in operation 2
I want to use rest batch processing with oracle ADF based rest API's to insert one row and then take the table row ID in the payload from that insert and use that ID in a second operation inside the batch to update a different row.  If either fail I want the entire batch to rollback.  Is this possible in one batch call?
I cannot find anything that says this is possible.
